# Magento 2 How to store quote custom data into sales_invoice

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created certain custom **columns** in quote, order, invoice and shipment tables and all the table columns are labeled with the **same**. Now i am able to store the data in quote and quote->order table successfully by now i want to store quote data to invoice table using **observer-event** when i generate invoice.

**Need some help in achieving this.**

**Thanks**